# spring crudRepository null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

Есть класс @Entity ResultCode, далее есть интерфейс который extends CrudRepository, в классе контроллера я могу пользоваться resultCodeRepository интерфейсом, но в других классах появляется NullPointerException. Как решить проблему?

Класс POJO

```
    @Entity(name="result_codes")
public class ResultCode implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_rescode", sequenceName = "rescode_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence_rescode")
    private Integer result_id;

    @Column(name="result_code",unique = true)
    private String resultCode;

    @Column(name="result_descr")
    private String resultDescr;
```

Класс Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ResultCodeRepository extends CrudRepository<ResultCode, Integer> {
    Optional<ResultCode> getResultCodeByResultCode(String string);
}
```

Класс Controller где работает..

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/index")
public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    private ResultCodeRepository resultCodeRepository;

   @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<ResultCode> getAllUsers() {
        return resultCodeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Класс где не работает

```
@Component
public class Test  {
    private ResultCodeRepository resultCodeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setResultCodeRepository(ResultCodeRepository resultCodeRepository){
        this.resultCodeRepository = resultCodeRepository;
    }

    public void persistAll(){
        resultCodeRepository.save(new ResultCode("90","Все хорошо"));
        System.out.println("rescode has been saved");
    }
}
```

Класс main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       Test test = new Test();
        test.persistAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы создаете свой экземпляр Test? Он у вас имеет аннотацию `@Component`, а значит должен быть просканирован спрингом и должен быть добавлен в контейнер бинов, чтобы сработала `@Autowired`. Если вы создаете бин вручную, логично, что он будет пустой

Comment: Я понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так делать нельзя. Если вы создаете экземпляр класса через new, то контейнер спринга ничего о нем не знает, соответственно, не может инжектить в него бины. Вы выходите за пределы контексте спринга, поэтому и все, что вы пытаетесь проинжектить не инициализируется, соответсвенно, вы получаете данное исключение.
Если Вам нужно прямо из главного класса проинжектить бин и вызвать у него метод, то можно сделать так:

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner init(Test test) {
        return (args) -> {
            test.persistAll()
        };
    }

}
```